# Shipping method set/unset in checkout based on custom radio button selection

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How can I achieve this.

I have two custom radion button in checkout page, based on that radion button selection, I would like to set/unset available shipping method.

Let say we have 'pickup' and 'delivery' two radio buttons. Now when user select pickup, I would like to show only pickup shipping method and hide my custom logical 'custom_shipping_method'.

And similarly, when selecting 'delivery' radio, I would like to only show 'custom_shipping_method' and hide pickup shipping method.

I have tried it with this filter hook **'woocommerce_package_rates'** but no luck.